# Chisel: Why do I get a warning when output of Mux is of type SInt?

Tags: chisel

The code compiles correctly but I get a warning:

```
[warn] PC_RVI.scala:22: Mux of Bits instantiated, emits SInt in class TOP_pack.PC_RVI
```

the part of the code giving the warning looks like this:

```
PC_input1 := Mux(io.branch, io.imme, UInt(4))
PC_input2 := Mux(io.PC_or_rs1, io.rs1, PC_reg)
```

where `imme` and `rs1` are of type `SInt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your signals must be of the same type SInt. As we see on the given code is not same :

```
PC_input1 := Mux(io.branch, io.imme, UInt(4))
```

io.imme is a SInt() and UInt(4) not. Is your PC_input1 is a SInt() ?

If you want to avoid warnings use the same type for all variables.

Comment: I have used .toUInt to cast to integer since PC_input should be of type UInt now the warnings are gone. Thanks.